# How do I get depend on all artifacts from a group of a version from maven?

Tags: java, maven, lucene

I'm new to Maven and I'm trying to build a project for the first time. I want to write some code that depends on apache lucene. Here's a [list of artifacts in maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene) that I'm trying to get.

Is there any way instead of explicitly listing each artifact, I could simply depend on all artifacts of a given version? I tried this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which gave me the error

> 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for org.apache.lucene:*:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 19, column 19

I can verify that I can download dependencies when I explicitly state them. IE this works fine:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I realize depending on everything in lucene is probably sub-optimal, but for doing something quick-and-dirty I'd hate to have to manually populate all these little lucene libraries. What is the typical practice for getting a large set of related dependencies in maven?

Comment: maybe you can try adding BOM https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040537/725306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **you can't**. Remember you just do this once and later you can simply copy-paste dependencies (not very DRY though). Also consider creating an archetype that will quickly create a skeleton with all required dependencies (for quick and dirty projects).

Longer answer: well, you can work around that. Create a separate `pom.xml` with:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

and declare all Lucene dependencies there manually, one after another. Once and for all. Later you can simply add a dependency to your `pom.xml` (that is to `groupId`/`artifactId`/`version` defined there) which will transitively include all dependencies of that `pom.xml`.

Talking about transitivity: if you depend on a JAR in maven and that JAR has other dependencies, you get that transitive dependencies implicitly. Examine Lucene `pom`s, maybe it's enough to import few of them and rely on transitive dependencies?

Answer (score -3):

Inside a single dependency for a groupId add different artifactId's

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is this a relatively new feature? I just tried this in maven 3.0.5 and it was not allowed.

Comment: This works with maven 3.5.0. I am currently using the same. Please try it

Comment: Using `Apache Maven 3.6.3`, this does not work at all. `[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /foobar/pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'artifactId' (position: START_TAG seen ...</artifactId>\n <artifactId>... @76:25)  @ line 76, column 25`

Comment: this does not work, and is misleading. Can this answer be removed?