# Getting all artifacts for a given group and version in Maven

Tags: maven, vaadin, dependency-management

Is it possible to get list all artifacts for a given group ID and version in maven in any web-site/link?

I am trying to get all Vaadin dependencies using Maven and I have the following details available:

```
<groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
<version>7.1.6</version>
```

I am using the

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

command to get the dependencies to a folder.

I am aware that I have to specify each dependency by hand such as

vaadin-shared
vaadin-server etc.

I just want to be able to get the list of all these artifacts by providing a group id and version number above and then generate individual dependency entries like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I have checked the answer here:
[How do I get depend on all artifacts from a group of a version from maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772290/how-do-i-get-depend-on-all-artifacts-from-a-group-of-a-version-from-maven)

and looked at the maven entries here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin

Thanks.

========================================================

**Updated: 7 Oct 2013**

As mentioned by Robert below, the central repository advanced search (http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav) helped me what I was looking for.
Also, I tried the REST API (http://search.maven.org/#api) and that too works fine. I am just a step away from writing a sample java code that will fetch the details using a REST API and convert it to a nice XML format that I can now simply copy to my intended POM file :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [search page on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch) has an advanced button, which gives you a page where you can fill all kinds of things, for instance [only the groupId and version](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.vaadin%22%20AND%20v%3A%227.1.6%22)

There should be a REST-api for this, have a look at the Sonatype Nexus documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much. Looks Great. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. I will also look at the REST API and try to figure out a small code for that. Really appreciate it.

Comment: even the REST API works. I am trying to figure out the JSON/XML response properly, may be I will use Google gson library. But thanks for the great tip.