# Is a maven BOM for Apache Lucene/SOLR available?

Tags: solr, lucene, maven-3

Because of the many artifacts of the Lucene / SOLR project I was looking for a Maven BOM file.
I cannot find one. Is there indeed no BOM file for this project?
And if not present, does anyone know the background of this omission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest you will get to a BOM, is [`solr-parent`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-parent/8.5.1). It pulls a lot of Solr dependencies transitively and keeps the versions synchronous.